# CS50 - filter-less - Pointers not allowing me to create file

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, cs50

Can anyone help? I'm trying to complete CS50's filter-less but I keep getting the error. I feel like I am not understanding pointers properly. Could anyone explain or point me to a good resource?

```
helpers.c:17:8: error: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'BYTE *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    pb = &image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: helpers] Error 1
```

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int h = height;
    int w = width;

    float rgbsum;

    int *pb;
    int *pg;
    int *pr;

    pb = &image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
    pg = &image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
    pr = &image[h][w].rgbtRed;

    /*
    Average Pixel Value:
    Set RGB all to the same. {R, B , G} = rbgsum
    Average the sum of all colors. (R+G+B) / 3.0
    Return new values back to RBG.
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            rgbsum = round((&b + &g + &r) / 3.0);
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = rgbsum;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = rgbsum;
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = rgbsum;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Try `unsigned char *pg, *pr, *pb;` instead of them being pointers to`int`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a specific requirement for the exercise to utilize pointer and/or work variables, your function could be simplified as shown in the following code snippet.

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int h = height;
    int w = width;

    float rgbsum;

    /*
    Average Pixel Value:
    Set RGB all to the same. {R, B , G} = rbgsum
    Average the sum of all colors. (R+G+B) / 3.0
    Return new values back to RBG.
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            rgbsum = ((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3.0 + 0.5);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = rgbsum;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = rgbsum;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = rgbsum;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This avoids pointers altogether.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be helpful to know how "RGBTRIPLE" is defined.

However from the error you got it seems that each colour is stored on an unsigned char.

If I'm correct there are two easy ways of solving it.

**Option 1. - Change the values type to BYTE pointer or unsigned char pointer**

```
BYTE *pb;
BYTE *pg;
BYTE *pr;

pb = &image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
pg = &image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
pr = &image[h][w].rgbtRed;
```

**Option 2. - Don't use pointers at all and let the unsigned char be converted to int**

```
int pb;
int pg;
int pr;

pb = image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
pg = image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
pr = image[h][w].rgbtRed;
```